# How can I avoid drop hacks and crash hacks on Battle.net?

Tags: starcraft

From time to time I play StarCraft: Brood War on Battle.net since it's still a pretty good game even after all the years. The only problem I have are players that come and mass drop hack everyone, or even worse, mass crash hack (causing Starcraft to crash) everyone playing games.

I have found some programs that claim to help protect against drop hacks online but I don't know if I can trust them. I also didn't find programs to protect against crash hacks although I think they exist (because people in SC tell me they do).

Does anyone know of a way to deal with this problem?

Comment: These hacks essentially attack the server side to prevent access, or outright disconnect players, from battle.net.  Anything that purports to "protect" you from them are trojans, almost guaranteed.  Server side issues are something only Blizzard can fix.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution that can help is to have /dnd on when playing, and ignore a person who is threatening to crash you or who you think might. This will prevent the text character issue, which was the most widely proliferated drophack a while back because it's essentially undetectable.

If that doesn't work, there are some legitimate programs are out there that will help prevent these crashes, but they're generally incorporated as a part of a larger hack. Using these fully will have features that are at risk of detection by Warden, Blizzard's anti-hack. Stick to mainstream sites and read forum discussions about programs before you risk trying them out.